# How to get all data from a Eloquent Model with it's relations?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

My question is how to get the data from an eloquent model with its relation?

Imagine 3 tables:

**users**:

```
| id | name | email           |
|----|------|-----------------|
| 1  | name | email@email.com |
```

**companies**:

```
| id | name | user_id | address_id |
|----|------|---------|------------|
| 1  | name | 1       | 1          |
```

**addresses**:

```
| id | zip    | state |
|----|--------|-------|
| 1  | 101010 | LA    |
```

And the relations:

**Company.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}

public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Address::class);
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

**Address.php**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

In this case how I can get let's say all the companies with their related users and addresses?

on `Company::whereHas('users')->get();` getting:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.company_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`company_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))'
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: A company should have many users, and a user should belong to at least one company. Try placing a `company_id` column in your users table and fill the column with the respective company id.

Comment: The problem is that for my solution I actually don't need multiple users for the companies. In my case, one user represents a company.

Comment: If one user represents a company why do you need a users table and a companies table?

Comment: so in my case would be 2 types of users. One would be a regular user, second is a user which represents a company. That's why decided to store all the users in one table and for specific users only to fill out the companies table @adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in the **company** model, the user and the address methods were referencing with the `hasOne()` method to other models. It was looking for a secondary key to be in the users' table, not in the companies one.

Simply swapping up the `hasOne()` with `belongsTo` fixed out my issue.

So now my **Company.php** model looks like:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function address()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}
```

**Address.php**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}
```

Now we can get all the list of companies with their user and address by `Company::with('user')->with('address')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the hasOne with BelongsTo and vice versa;

**Company.php**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function address()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}
```

**Address**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}
```

and then in **Controller**

```
Company::whereHas('users')
    ->whereHas('address')
    ->with('users')->with('address')
    ->get();
```

Comment: for my case the company is represented only by one user.

So on registering the users on the site, they are divided into the regular users and user that represents a company.

Comment: in this case just swape the hasOne to belongsTo and vice versa;